# Getting authentication Logging (success and failures) in Python Flask

Tags: python, authentication

Complete newbie to Python (and programming!) here, so please bear with.

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to get authentication logging working for a test web app. Could anyone please spot where I'm going wrong? Code snippet below:

````
from project.api.models import User
from project import db, bcrypt
from sqlalchemy import exc, or_
from project.api.utils import get_user
import logging

auth_blueprint = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

logger = logging.getLogger('auth')

@auth_blueprint.route('/auth/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        ip = request.remote_addr
        try:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                auth_token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
                if auth_token:
                    logger.info('Authentication Success for: %s from %s' % (email, ip))
                    response = make_response(redirect(url_for("questions.feed")))
                    response.set_cookie('Authorization', auth_token.decode(), httponly=True)
                    return response
            logger.error('AuthenticationFailure for: %s from %s' % (email, ip))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
        flash("Login Failed")```
````

Comment: Please post a specific error and what you tried to do to fix it.

Comment: So that's where I'm struggling to be honest, as it doesn't appear to be throwing any errors, but the log file isn't being populated with anything.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. This would require at least the HTML file, HTTP query, the rest of the log file etc...